# How would you test a method that returns a promise using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, es6-promise

I would like to know how a method that returns a promise that resolves another method can be tested with jest.

For example:-

```
    getUser() {
    const getListFromDatabase= this.getListFromDatabase.bind(this);
    const getListFromUser= this.getListFromUser.bind(this);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const myList = Cookies.get('myList');
      if (myList) {
        resolve(myList);
      } else if (CONFIGURATION.ENABLED) {
        resolve(getListFromDatabase());
      } else {
        resolve(getListFromUser());
      }
    });
  },
```

`getListFromDatabase` and `getListFromUser` are other methods in my main object.

`getUser()` is a method in my main object.

So now I want to write a unit test with jest that would test that we resolved an array (myList) if the cookie was found, we resolved `getListFromDatabase()` if the global configuration variable was enabled or else `getListFromUser()`.

The fact that I return a new promise that resolves makes me confused which way to go, with `expect().resolves` or `getUser().then(data => expect(data)..)`

Comment: You can make the test async and wait it to test the final result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [flush-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flush-promises) to make the promises resolve, then you don't need to wait for the promise.

example :

```
test('flushPromises', async () => {
  let a;
  let b;

  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    a = 1;
  }).then(() => {
    b = 2;
  })

  await flushPromises();

  expect(a).toBe(1);
  expect(b).toBe(2);
});
```

Comment: How can this be used to test my method? I don't see any relation.

Comment: Can we stay away from async and await?

Comment: its just synthetic sugar the await and async - works the same way as promise

Comment: just add flushPromises().then(expect("what you want to test"));